# Running number of wcf instances

Tags: multithreading, wcf, service, instance

My wcf service hosted in IIS uses dlls of external engine  that doesn't support multithreading. So I want to run number wcf instances that each uses different dlls folder of the same external engine. How can I do it in WCF hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

While I don’t fully follow the usage scenario, the following general guidance may be helpful:

**Set the Instance context:**
The instancing behavior (set by using the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode` property) controls how the InstanceContext is created in response to incoming messages. By default, each InstanceContext is associated with one user-defined service object, so (in the default case) setting the InstanceContextMode property also controls the instancing of user-defined service objects. The InstanceContextMode enumeration defines the instancing modes.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall ...
```

**Set the Concurrency mode:**
Concurrency is the control of the number of threads active in an InstanceContext at any one time. This is controlled by using the ServiceBehaviorAttribute.ConcurrencyMode with the ConcurrencyMode enumeration.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple ...
```

**Configure throttling values:**

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior  name="Throttled">
      <serviceThrottling 
        maxConcurrentCalls="x" 
        maxConcurrentSessions="x" 
        maxConcurrentInstances="x"
      />
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have a wcf service, which should call a 3rd party application, which is not designed to support a multi threaded calls. 
On each request my service should create a file and call this external application. The processing a relatively slow,  about 10 sec,  so I want to parallelize a processing, by definning a webfarm on iis  . Let's say that I will define 5 workers on iis.  this means that I will need a 5 instances of this external application,probably in 5 different folders. 
What will the best way to do it?  how will each worker to know what instance to use?

Comment: What "framework" is used to host the 3rd party application (i.e. Windows Service, Console App, IIS Site)?  What is the interface used to communicate with the 3rd party app?

Comment: 3rd party application runs in different process.On each request my service should create a file and call this external application.